# Default timestamps are of different time zone in different mysql tables

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

**Server Version & `gorm` package:**

```sh
❯ docker exec -it mysql mysqld --version
mysqld  Ver 5.7.29 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server (GPL))

❯ docker exec -it mysql mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.29, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

```golang
import "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
```

**Two tables:**

```sql
mysql> desc t1;
+------------+-------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field      | Type              | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+------------+-------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| ...        |                   |      |     |                   |                |
| created_at | timestamp         | YES  |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
+------------+-------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+

mysql> desc t2;
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field          | Type             | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| ...            | ...              | ...  | ... | ...               | ...            |
| initiated_at   | timestamp        | YES  |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

**The `gorm` model while defining `stuct{}` is as following:**

```golang
// t1
type T1 struct {
    ID uint `gorm:"primary_key"`
    // others are here
    // ...

    CreatedAt  time.Time `gorm:"timestamp;default:CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" json:"created_at" form:"created_at" query:"created_at" sql:"DEFAULT:current_timestamp"`
}

// t2 ...
type T2 struct {
    ID uint `gorm:"primary_key"`
    // others are here
    // ...
    InitiatedAt  time.Time `gorm:"timestamp;default:CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" json:"initiated_at" form:"initiated_at" query:"initiated_at" sql:"DEFAULT:current_timestamp"`
}
```

**insert with uninitialized timestamp**

```golang
dbSource := fmt.Sprintf(
    "%s:%s@tcp(%s:%s)/%s?charset=utf8&parseTime=True&loc=Local",
    cnf.Username,
    cnf.Password,
    cnf.Host,
    cnf.Port,
    cnf.DBName,
)

db, err := gorm.Open("mysql", dbSource)
if err != nil {
    logrus.Warn("Got error when connect database:", err)
    return err
}

t1 := T1{} // created_at is not set
t2 := T2{} // initiated_at is not set

tx := db.Begin()
defer func() {
    if r := recover(); r != nil {
        logrus.Error("Rolling back")
        tx.Rollback()
    }
}()
// If failed to begin transaction
if err := tx.Error; err != nil {
    return err
}

if err := db.Create(&t1).Error; err != nil {
    logrus.Warn(err)
    // rollback the transaction in case of error
    tx.Rollback()
    return derror.ErrorBadRequest
}
if err := db.Create(&t2).Error; err != nil {
    logrus.Warn(err)
    // rollback the transaction in case of error
    tx.Rollback()
    return derror.ErrorBadRequest
}

// Or commit the transaction
if err := tx.Commit().Error; err != nil {
    logrus.Warn(err)
    // rollback the transaction in case of error
    tx.Rollback()
    return derror.ErrorBadRequest
}
```

**What I see, when do select queries**

```sql
mysql> select * from t1;
+-----+---------------------+
| ... | created_at          |
+-----+---------------------+
| ... | 2020-03-24 02:38:26 |
+-----+---------------------+

mysql> select * from t2;
+-----+---------------------+
| ... | initiated_at        |
+-----+---------------------+
| ... | 2020-03-23 20:38:26 |
+-----+---------------------+
```

**Expectation:**

Note that, I am in `asia/dhaka`(+06:00) region. And the time of `created_at` of `t1` table is the BST current time of my region. On the other hand, the time of `initiated_at` of `t2` table is the UTC current time.

But I expect that both the times are the same (I mean the either UTC or BST).

**Want to know:**

- The reason why the two times are of different region.
- Any solution so that both the times are of same region

Comment: I have noticed an important thing and that is changing from `CreatedAt time.time` to `WrittenAt time.time` in `struct` while defining `gorm` model, makes `gorm` to set the default time in UTC current time. May be it is because of `gorm.Model` that has `CreatedAt time.time` field.

Comment: that happend because `WrittenAt` set by MySql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Table `t1`, `CreatedAt` set by  `Gorm` in local timezone since you use `loc=Local`.

Ref: https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/blob/master/callback_create.go#L32

And in Table `t2`, `initiated_at` not set by `Gorm` it set by `Mysql` since you use default value as `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in `MySql`.

**Solution:**

You can change `Gorm` timezone to UTC using `loc=UTC` in connection.

Or

You can set your local timezone as `Mysql` timezone.
Note that sets the location for time.Time values but does not change MySQL's time_zone setting.For that see the time_zone system variable, which can also be set as a DSN parameter.

Ref: https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql#loc